# (Python) Printing only the last line in row from a CSV file and I want the entire row with all the lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Hi all I'm new to coding and trying my first project but I have a problem. After importing my csv and reading the rows I am appending all the individual rows to a variable but when I print out that variable it only gives the last line in that row and I need all the lines in that row. I would appreciate some help. below is my code in python 3.9

```
import csv

path = "stuff/foods.csv"
file = open(path, newline='') 
reader = csv.reader(file)  

header = next(reader)
data = []
for row in reader:
    # row = [Foods, Serving_Size, Calories, Carbs, Fat, Protien, Fiber]
    foods = str(row[0])
    serving_size = int(row[1])
    calories = int(row[2])
    carbs = int(row[3])
    fat = int(row[4])
    protien = int(row[5])
    fiber = int(row[6]) 

    data.append([foods, serving_size, calories, carbs, fat, protien, fiber])

user_input = ""

while user_input.lower() != "quit":
    user_input = input ("Would you like the menu?: ").lower()
    if user_input == "yes":
        print(foods)
    elif user_input == "quit":
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for every row in the csv, you overwrite the variable `foods` so it makes sense that when you print this at the end, it prints the last value.

You save the information in a list called `data`, so to print all information, you need that list. I think this will work for you:

```
import csv

path = "stuff/foods.csv"
file = open(path, newline='') 
reader = csv.reader(file)  

header = next(reader)
data = []
for row in reader:
    # row = [Foods, Serving_Size, Calories, Carbs, Fat, Protien, Fiber]
    foods = str(row[0])
    serving_size = int(row[1])
    calories = int(row[2])
    carbs = int(row[3])
    fat = int(row[4])
    protien = int(row[5])
    fiber = int(row[6]) 

    data.append([foods, serving_size, calories, carbs, fat, protien, fiber])

user_input = ""

while user_input.lower() != "quit":
    user_input = input ("Would you like the menu?: ").lower()
    if user_input == "yes":
        for i in data:
            print(i[0])
    elif user_input == "quit":
        break
```

Also, you open the file, with `file = open(path,newline='')`, but I don't see you closing it. It is good practice to do so, and there is a standard Pythonic way using `with`. You can find out more [here](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/with-statement-in-python).